# Change all button colors individually on click in View for MVC5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, asp.net-mvc-5

Right now I have a list of button created using a foreach loop from getting the amount of entries in a database using:

```
@model IEnumerable<myProject.Models.listItems>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
}

<h2>List</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   foreach (var item in Model){
   <input id="vote" type="button" value="Vote" position="relative" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px; float:right" onclick="changeColor()"/>
   }
}
```

I want to be able to change the button colors when they're clicked and currently I'm using these javascript code to do it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var voteBtn = document.getElementById('vote');
    voteBtn.onclick = function changeColor() {
        if($(this).hasClass('clicked')){
            $(this).removeClass('clicked');
            $(this).addClass('un-clicked');
            $(this).val('Vote');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('un-clicked').addClass('clicked');
            $(this).val('VOTED');
        }
    }
```

Right now the problem is that I can only change the color of the first button.
E.g. if I have 5 entries in my database I will have 5 buttons but only the first button will change color on click and the rest is non-responsive.
And I'm not sure what I can do to fix it.

Here is my css as well:

```
.clicked{
        background-color:#D8173B !important;
}

.unclicked{
        background-color:Highlight !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could possibly do this with jquery like this:

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

Also, please note that you end up with identical IDs (#vote) using your method which is not valid. Better to use a class on the button.

Comment: Unfortunately that made all the buttons non-responsive :(

Comment: What exactly do you mean by unresponsive? Did you remove the id's and target the buttons with classes in your javascript? Using my code, do all buttons now change colour?

Comment: It works now, it seems like I had some sort of syntax error that prevented the code from running correctly